# How to use hindi content in jsp file?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

while using hindi content in jsp , inside either in div or

tag.it is showing some different symbols at the place of my text.
how can I use the hindi content in my jsp file.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```